# Close Application Instead Go Previous Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am learning android and want close application if my int value is 1. I want when user click on Navigation arrow icon. Currently I am trying below code but instead close application, its sending me on Previous Activity. I have verified that blocked value is 1 but dont know why its not closing application.
My code is like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("blocked",""+blocked);
        if(blocked==1){
            finish();
            return false;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Let me know if someone can help me for achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Why Down Vote without single comment?

Comment: Hi, what should happen when the user launches your app again from launcher? Should your app resume on this activity or should it start from the beginning?

Comment: @EugenPechanec its starting from splash activity. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can finish your first activity as soon as you launch the second. That way when you're coming "back" from the second activity there's nothing to come back to and the app will close.

Or you can call [`finishAffinity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) which will finish all activities in current task.

Read more: [Understanding Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. Its working fine. I have used finish first activity before start new activity as You have told. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be using this:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
startActivity(homeIntent);
```